# What if the user edits device date to bypass logic check that compares current date with a constant date or so?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, date

I am making an app that makes a comparison between two dates - one being the current device date and the other being hardcoded date. But one way to fail this logic is, lets say, the hardcoded date is passed and the user changes the device date to a date, which is before the hardcoded date. So in this case the app fails. 
How do I avoid this ?

```
NSDate * currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate * hardcodedDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithString:@"2013-07-21 11:15:30 +0700"];
NSComparisonResult result = [currentDate compare:hardcodedDate];

if (!result == NSOrderedDescending) 
{
    // do something 
}
```

Comment: The most common case is that the device date is reset back to its initial default.  You can check for this and put up a message - "Set your date, stupid!" (or something like that).

Comment: @HotLicks Don't call your customers stupid. Show some respect.

Comment: @neilco - That's why I said "something like that" -- "You idiot!" is much better.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to get the current date from a web service (using https) in order to verify the date of the users device.

Comment: @neilco, original was a typo. HTTPS will prevent (or make it hard) for the user to substitute the connection to the webservice with some other service.

Comment: Using HTTPS doesn't prevent MITM attacks. In fact, I use such a technique to debug HTTPS calls. [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com) makes this easy.

Comment: I still stand by my edit—the transport is irrelevant to the answer. The pertinent point is to retrieve the time from an external source. How the OP does that is not important here.

Comment: If you really want to hide the fact you're retrieving the date from an external source, then do it in plain sight. Make a HTTP call to any service (the more innocuous, the better) that keeps their server time synchronised and then read the time from the `Date` header in the HTTP response.